# How to use ST_GeomFromText('Point($1 $2)', 4326) inside pg_query_params call

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis

I am new to postgresql/postgis and would like to insert a geometry point type into my database with a pg_query_param call. I tried the following:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO userloc (email, latitude, longitude, the_geom) VALUES($1, $2, $3, ST_GeomFromText('POINT($3 $2)', 4326))";
$rs = pg_query_params($con, $query, array('%$#^@@gmail.com', 0, 0));
```

but this yields an error:

```
Warning: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry HINT: "POINT($3" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry in /var/www/html/signup.php on line 26
```

I tried removing the single parens from around point, but that gives this error:

```
Warning: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2" LINE 1: ...geom) VALUES($1, $2, $3, ST_GeomFromText(POINT($3 $2), 4326)... ^ in /var/www/html/signup.php on line 26
```

I realize I can simply insert the latitude and longitude and then separately use these columns to generate the_geom column, but there must be a way to do this in one command while still benefiting from using this params function rather than the usual pg_query. Any recommendations are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the same problems with PDO? Might be how you're using the super low-level Postgres driver directly.

Comment: Almost the same problem as here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27942964/1499698

Comment: @pozs Thanks for the suggestion, but their proposed workaround of passing a single string param to the ST function still generates a parsing error.

Comment: @tadman I don't have the PDO modules installed. I may try this workaround in a few days but not now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error in PostgreSQL parametrised query from C# but works in pgAdmin III](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942448/parse-error-in-postgresql-parametrised-query-from-c-sharp-but-works-in-pgadmin-i)

Comment: @CauchyKun no, it's the exact same problem: you either concatenate the geometry at client & pass a single string as parameter i.e. `'POINT(0 0)'` or concatenate the parameters in PostgreSQL, like `'POINT(' || $1 || ' ' || $2 || ')'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ST_MakePoint](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html), which takes numeric inputs and can be used for parametrized queries. `$query` should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO userloc (email, latitude, longitude, the_geom)
VALUES($1, $2, $3, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($3, $2), 4326));
```

Comment: thanks so much! This worked like a charm. For some reason I thought ST_MakePoint itself had to be set as a parameter string so I was surrounding it with quotes when I tried this approach.